# Set Image colours while theme change

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In WP7 suppose we are having a TextBlock with Foreground as **DEFAULT** and we change the theme of phone than foreground will be adjusted automatically so that its(TextBlock's) text can be seen properly with any **theme** . Is there any way to do same to some if we are having **image** kind of control so that the control can be seen with any available **THEME** of WP7 in proper OR presentable manner

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can adjust the image to the dark/light theme, using the `PhoneDarkThemeVisibility` and `PhoneLightThemeVisibility` resources. I would suggest using a ValueConverter.

You can read more [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)